# Why does setup.py usually not have a shebang line?

Tags: python, setup.py

Looking at a random selection of well-known Python packages, why is there a general trend to not include a `#!/usr/bin/env python` line at the top of `setup.py`? I know that the usual recommended way of interacting with the file is something like:

```
python setup.py install
```

rather than

```
./setup.py install
```

but is there a good reason for this?

These packages do not include a shebang: [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/setup.py), [lxml](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/setup.py), [six](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/default/setup.py), [virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/setup.py), [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/setup.py)

But these do: [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/setup.py), [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/setup.py), [setuptools](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/default/setup.py)

Comment: The `#!` line does not hurt since it is a comment. People probably are lazy.

Comment: Personally, I often forget about it (not just for `setup.py`, but for other scripts too)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setup.py` is going to do the installation for the Python interpreter you are running it with and its library path. A shebang would define that interpreter and that is not desired by the developer.

Even if you have a `setup.py` with a shebang, you should still run the file with the interpreter before it. It prevents you from questions like "Where the hack is the package gone!?"

Answer (score 2):

In this setting, the shebang offers few benefits, and a big drawback:

- The shebang is useful for reasons that are irrelevant here:

  - It eases using a script repeatedly (less typing)
  - It clarifies how/what a script will do when looking at the source.
- The shebang necessarily determines the interpreter used to run it. I've written `setup.py` scripts which I've tested as `python setup.py install` and `python3 setup.py install`; in these cases, I simply don't know what to put in the shebang.

Answer (score 1):

Because python packages must work on Windows platform too.
`python setup.py install` is universal command

Comment: The shebang does not hurt on any platform. The argument that is has to run on Windows is valid, but it does not make any difference to have that line.

Comment: The shebang won't avoid setup.py to work in windows so I don't see how this answer the question.

Comment: After reading this, I looked at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) and found that actually `/usr/bin/env` is portable even to Windows.

Comment: That would be great @erip. However, I think some people do not use the launcher - for example I read that it does not come with Anaconda installs.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `sh` in various distributions are almost always located in `/bin`, or at least in a folder symlinked to `/bin`. And they almost always follow a same standard. So using `#!/bin/sh` works in almost all cases, except for on Windows machine, of course. That's something totally different.

Python, on the other hand, is a bit messy on this department. First, not all distributions have python binary stored or symlinked to `/bin/python`, for example Ubuntu still only have binary of python in `/usr/bin/python`. On the other hand, even for those which have `python` in `/bin`, on some OS, like Fedora and OS X, `/bin/python` means Python2, while on others, like Arch linux, `/bin/python` means Python3. Considering Python2 and Python3 codes are not entirely compatible, if using `#!/bin/python` and run the script with

```
./setup.py
```

it could cause issues if `python3` was used as interpreter on your machine but really `python2` was meant by the script author.

Comment: You shouldn't expect to find a `/bin/python` on Ubuntu.